# How do I reverse the effects of fitViewportToMapItems?

Tags: dictionary, object, qml

Essentially I want to undo the changes caused by calling fitViewportToMapItems. Is there a way that I can reset or go back to the previous screen after calling this function?

Comment: please provide [mcve]

Comment: How about you watch for `center` and `zoomLevel` changes and provide some kind of "undo" / "redo" feature so you can move backward (or forward) thru changes? Then, whatever change you do, including fitViewportToMapItems can be undone/redone.